# Retornar os elementos de uma lista de forma randomizada

Tags: python, lista, random

Eu tenho uma array gerada por um `string.split()`, e o valor dessa string é obtido por um `input`.

Ou seja:

```
string = input("Digite os Nomes separados por Vírgula")
arrTeste = string.split(",")
```

O número de elementos no array é indefinido, visto que o usuário pode digitar 5 nomes, 10 nomes... etc

**É possível retornar todos os elementos do array de forma aleatória?**

Exemplo (Supondo que o usuário tenha digitado os três nomes abaixo no `input`):

```
arrTeste = ["Junior", "Gabriel", "Henrique"]
```

**O output desejado seria algo como:**

```
print(funcaoAleatorizar)  ## suposição da função

@Gabriel, @Junior, @Henrique  ## output do terminal
```

Ainda tenho o detalhe que preciso concanetar um `@` antes dos elementos gerados, mas isso eu mesmo faço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *É possível retornar todos os elementos do array de forma aleatória?*

Sim, basta usar a [função `shuffle` do módulo `random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
from random import shuffle

arrTeste = ["Junior", "Gabriel", "Henrique"]
shuffle(arrTeste)

print(', '.join('@' + nome for nome in arrTeste))
```

Com isso os elementos da lista são "embaralhados" aleatoriamente.

Depois, basta imprimir os nomes com o `@` na frente, e separados por vírgula, conforme desejado.

---

Lembrando que `shuffle` altera a lista *in-place*.

Mas se você quer manter a lista original intacta, uma alternativa é usar [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
from random import sample

arrTeste = ["Junior", "Gabriel", "Henrique"]
embaralhado = sample(arrTeste, len(arrTeste))
print(', '.join('@' + nome for nome in embaralhado))
print(arrTeste) # lista original permanece intacta
```

`sample` gera uma amostra da lista, garantindo que não há elementos repetidos. Mas como no segundo parâmetro eu passei o tamanho da lista, então no fim ele irá gerar uma amostra do tamanho da lista (e como ele garante que não há repetição, o resultado terá todos os elementos da lista em ordem aleatória). E a lista original permanecerá intacta.

Comment: Nossa amigo! É bem mais simples do que eu esperava, que incrível! Muito obrigado! Esclarecedor e didático.